# Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I am trying to migrate my app from jsf 1.2 to 2.1. I wrote a sample facelet page and tried to access it. Getting following exception. Not sure what causes this issue. If execute only this page (by removing all code and libraries related to my project, this page rendering properly). Any help on what could cause this issue would be really helpful.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Header count exceeded allowed maximum: 128
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.addValue(MimeHeaders.java:347) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.addHeader(Response.java:351) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addHeader(Response.java:1110) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addHeader(ResponseFacade.java:502) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:202) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:202) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:202) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:202) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addHeader(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:202) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.<init>(ExternalContextImpl.java:137) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextFactoryImpl.getExternalContext(ExternalContextFactoryImpl.java:73) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl.getFacesContext(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:93) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:583) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was related to faces-config.xml.  Header should be.

```
<faces-config version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
```

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't expect this kind of exception to occur then. What did you initially have? A JSF 1.2 one?

Comment: @BalusC, Yes initially I have 1.2 header. After cracking my head for almost 2 days. Removing/Adding each file from EAR, at the end it turned out it is faces-config header issue.

Answer (score -1):

Include this tag in your head element like this:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
```

Explanation on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Specifying_the_document.27s_character_encoding)

Comment: This meta tag is only used whenever the enduser opens a saved webpage from local disk file system. I.e. when the enduser opens a webpage and then does a *File>Save* in browser to save it on disk and then re-opens it from disk. It is NOT used when the page is served over HTTP. Instead, the one in the HTTP response header is been used.